# Changing className in react based on button click while avoiding more if / elses

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement

Got a small project that I've been working on for past couple weeks. Basic premise is that there is a stepper with steps. User can click on each of them and get a description of what are his to-do's of each step.
There is also a button to complete the step. At the moment I am stuck on the part with making the button work properly.

What I want: When user clicks button to complete step, that stepper item changes its styling (This case classname) to appear as if its complete, and the button get disabled for next step.

I'm now at the point with many if/elses that I no longer have any clue how to finish this task and even if I was to rewrite the if's and else's in a different way I have no clue how as I am pretty new to react.

Some code snippets:
**My parent component.**

```
class UserPage extends Component {
state = {
    currentStep: 1,
    pendingApproval: false
}

clickHandler(e, step) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ currentStep: step })
}

incrimentStep(e, step) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ currentStep: step, pendingApproval: true })
}

render() {
    return (
        <Grid>
            <Grid.Row columns={1}>
                <Grid.Column stretched>
                    <Stepper
                        clickHandler={this.clickHandler.bind(this)}
                        steps={this.props.user.process.steps}
                        pendingApproval={this.state.pendingApproval}
                    />
                </Grid.Column>
            </Grid.Row>

            <Grid.Row columns={1}>
                <Grid.Column stretched>
                    <Steps currentStep={this.state.currentStep} steps={this.props.user.process.steps} />
                    <StepButton
                        incrimentStep={this.incrimentStep.bind(this)}
                        currentStep={this.state.currentStep}
                        steps={this.props.user.process.steps}
                        pendingApproval={this.state.pendingApproval}
                    />
                </Grid.Column>
            </Grid.Row>
        </Grid>
    )
}
}

export default UserPage;
```

**My child component that I am trying to fix:**

```
class UserStepper extends Component {

render() {
    const steps_length = this.props.steps.length;
    let handler = this.props.clickHandler;
    // let incompleteStepsArray = []
    // let incompleteID = -1;
    let pendingApproval = this.props.pendingApproval;
    return (
        <div id="stepper-container">
            {this.props.steps.map(function (step, index) {
                if (step.isDone) {
                    if (index !== steps_length - 1) {
                        return (
                            <div key={index} className="completed">
                                <StepperFill
                                    index={index + 1}
                                    click={handler}
                                    steps={step[index]}
                                    class_name="completecontainer"
                                />
                                <CircleCompleted />
                            </div>
                        )
                    }
                    else {
                        return (
                            <div key={index} className="completed">
                                <StepperFill
                                    index={index + 1}
                                    click={handler}
                                    steps={step[index]}
                                    class_name="completecontainer"
                                />
                            </div>
                        )
                    }
                }
                else {
                    {/* incompleteID = incompleteID +1; */}
                    {/* console.log(incompleteStepsArray) */}
                    if (index !== steps_length - 1) {
                        return (
                            <div key={index} className="incompleted">
                                <StepperFill
                                    index={index + 1}
                                    click={handler}
                                    steps={step[index]}
                                    class_name="incompletecontainer"
                                />
                                <CircleIncompleted />
                            </div>
                        )
                    }
                    else {
                        return (
                            <div key={index} className="incompleted">
                                <StepperFill
                                    index={index + 1}
                                    click={handler}
                                    steps={step[index]}
                                    class_name="incompletecontainer"/>
                            </div>
                        )
                    }
                }
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
}

//Functional component to decide wether the stepper should be filled or left 
blank (Complete or Incomplete)
const StepperFill = (props) => {
return (<div onClick={(e) => props.click(e, props.index)} className= 
{props.class_name}>
    <p>Step {props.index}</p>
</div>
)
}

const CircleCompleted = () => {
return (
    <div className='circle_completed'>
        <Icon.Group size='big'>
            <Icon size='small' name='checkmark' color='green' />
        </Icon.Group>
    </div>
)
}

const CircleIncompleted = () => {
return (
    <div className='circle_incompleted'>
    </div>
)
}


export default UserStepper;
```

Sorry for the long code, no other idea how to show it otherwise that it would make sense as to what is happening. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: is user able to see previous stepper and current simultaneously? or are these consequetive events?

Comment: Stepper as a whole is a component user can see at all times. It works fine with the description and onClick event which updates description. It's only the "Complete step" button. 
It would obviously make sense to just change the state of step from incomplete to complete, however at the moment I am using an API for that data, and just want to set up a basic "Showcase" scenario where it just updates the CSS of Stepper Step

Answer (score 0):

Theres many ways you can refactor this but to disable the button a simple approach would be to add a `isNextBtnDisabled` to your state and pass it down to the button. Whenever you want your button disabled simple set that variable to true.

```
class UserPage extends Component {
state = {
  currentStep: 1,
  pendingApproval: false,
  isNextBtnDisabled: false,
}

clickHandler(e, step) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({ currentStep: step, isNextBtnDisabled: this.state.pendingApproval })
}

incrimentStep(e, step) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({ currentStep: step, pendingApproval: true, isNextBtnDisabled: true })
}

render() {
return (
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Row columns={1}>
            <Grid.Column stretched>
                <Stepper
                    clickHandler={this.clickHandler.bind(this)}
                    steps={this.props.user.process.steps}
                    pendingApproval={this.state.pendingApproval}
                />
            </Grid.Column>
        </Grid.Row>

        <Grid.Row columns={1}>
            <Grid.Column stretched>
                <Steps currentStep={this.state.currentStep} steps={this.props.user.process.steps} />
                <StepButton
                    incrimentStep={this.incrimentStep.bind(this)}
                    currentStep={this.state.currentStep}
                    steps={this.props.user.process.steps}
                    pendingApproval={this.state.pendingApproval}
                    disabled={this.state.isNextBtnDisabled}
                />
            </Grid.Column>
        </Grid.Row>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks Djtouchette, that’s pretty much why Imve had the pendingApproval state on there. I got it somewhat sorted, however once again it was comoleted with another if/else...Any suggestions on how could I refactor the code to make it more readable / that it would make more sense. Because now it looks like a 5year old just threw together a bunch of If/Else statements together. Still trying to learn the best practices, however it just keeps piling up because “It works”

Comment: Yeah definitely. As you can tell in your child component in your if/else statements your passing in almost the exact same data with a few tweaks. You could make use of some ternaries or a simple object lookup. I'll edit my answer with an example.